# Удаление команд с истории с помощью history

Tags: linux, history

Если ввести history в терминале, то выведется индексируемая история введённых команд.

Как удалить нужные элементы введённых команд **с помощью** встроенной программы history, а не удалением ненужных строчек из файла *.bash_history* ?

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750650/how-to-delete-history-of-last-10-commands-in-shell#14750744)

Comment: А позвольте поинтересоваться, чем удаление строчек из файла не угодило?)

Comment: Лишние действия. Открытие через редактор файл, выделение строчки, удаление, сохранение. А команда которая сама будет в истории для очистки ненужного в истории - быстрее. :D

Comment: `sed -i`  поможет сделать нужную команду. Но лучше просто перед командой писать пробел - тогда команда не сохраняется в истории.

Answer (score 2):

нужно использовать опицию -history -d 352  , числовое значение это номер строки